# How to write into the actual editing buffer

Tags: zsh, signals

I want "ls" to be written, but not executed, by stroking <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>. 
I'm using the following code, but it writes the command into the buffer that will be used to execute *after* hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>. I would like it to be written straightforwardly in some way, but I don't know how:

```
_prefill() {
  print -z "ls"
}

zle -N _prefill
bindkey '^r' _prefill
```

Comment: It is unclear where you want it written.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In widget functions, the editing buffer is exposed in the `$BUFFER` (whole buffer) and also `$LBUFFER` and `$RBUFFER` (the part of the buffer left and right of the cursor respectively). See `info zsh BUFFER`¹ for details. So here, you'd do:

```
_prefill() LBUFFER+=ls
```

`print -z` is to prefill the buffer for the next command so is typically used *outside* of zle widgets.

---

<sup>¹ you may need to install a `zsh-doc` package or equivalent as not all systems install the zsh documentation by default (other than the man pages which are not adequate for a manual this size). That documentation is also available online for the latest version. Here's the [link for the corresponding `BUFFER` index entry](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-BUFFER).</sup>

Comment: that's right! Thanks 

can you add this reference to the answer so that I accept it as the correct one? Thanks
http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html